# how to display tags

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Can you please let me know how can I display value in the same column conditionally as rows? ex: I have a table named tags in which there are two columns tag_id and tag_name.I want values in the tag_name appear next to next based on the condition.

```
tags

tag_id tag_name
1       abc 
2       xyz
3       def
4       ghi
```

Requirement tag_name : abc,ghi

Comment: Please tag only the relevant database you're using.

Comment: What is your database mysql or oracle??

Answer (score 0):

If your RDBMS is MySQL:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(tag_name)
from (
    select tag_id, tag_name, 1 as selector
    from tags
    where tag_id in (1, 4)
) as x    
group by selector
```

If your RDBMS is Oracle:

```
select LISTAGG(tag_name, ', ')
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY selector)
from (
  select tag_id, tag_name, 1 as selector
  from tags
  where tag_id in (1, 4)
)
```